# DataTables - Ignore empty moment date values when sorting

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm using DataTables and trying to ignore empty values on a date column which is based MomentJs when sorting.

e.g: `08 Nov 2016 09:47 pm`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqbWVa?editors=1010

Currently I have this and it sorts the values as expected but it also contains the empty cells.

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD MMM YYYY hh:mm a');
$('.table-data').DataTable();
```

I've tried the following custom sorting method which was originally posted here https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1178/sorting-dates-handling-null-values

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    'date-asc': function (a, b) {
      var x = Date.parse(a);
      var y = Date.parse(b);
      if (x == y) { return 0; }
      if (isNaN(x) || x < y) { return 1; }
      if (isNaN(y) || x > y) { return -1; }
    },
    'date-desc': function (a, b) {
      var x = Date.parse(a);
      var y = Date.parse(b);
      if (x == y) { return 0; }
      if (isNaN(y) || x < y) { return -1; }
      if (isNaN(x) || x > y) { return 1; }
    }
});

$('.table-data').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
      { type: 'date', targets: -1 }
    ]
});
```

But it seems no difference. I would really appreciate if you could help sort this issue.

**Update**
I want to move the empty valued row to the last so it won't be visible at the first place. Something like this 
http://jsfiddle.net/dnsL2oc4/2/

Comment: Do you want the rows to be removed when sorting the table or remove the rows when building the data table?

Comment: @DevDig I want to move the empty valued row to the last so it won't be visible at the first place. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/xshh5np8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD MMM YYYY hh:mm a');
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    'dateNonStandard-asc': function (a, b) {
      var x = Date.parse(a);
      var y = Date.parse(b);
      if (x == y) { return 0; }
      if (isNaN(x) || x < y) { return 1; }
      if (isNaN(y) || x > y) { return -1; }
    },
    'dateNonStandard-desc': function (a, b) {
      var x = Date.parse(a);
      var y = Date.parse(b);
      if (x == y) { return 0; }
      if (isNaN(y) || x < y) { return -1; }
      if (isNaN(x) || x > y) { return 1; }
    }
  });
  $('.table-data').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
      { type: 'dateNonStandard', targets: -1 }
    ]
  });
});
```

If you're doing something non-standard with sorting it'd be better to be clear about it ;-)

It seems to do what you want and I think your logic was sound but using moment was overkill. You might need to test it some more, though...

Comment: Thank you very much. This works!. I would really appreciate if you could add some comments next to each line. I'm not getting this.

Comment: Check this JSFiddle for comments: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/p5fee6hb/. Hope that helps.